# Passing in arguments to a called script

Tags: python, shell, nose, nosetests

I'm running `nosetests` on my project with `--with-snort` for Growl notifications.

The problem is that I have some lib files that I put on the path, so I have a custom python script at `bin/python`.

I have no issues running nose via my `bin/python` by doing `which nosetests` and using that executable - `bin/python /usr/local/bin/nosetests`. But now how do I pass in flags to `nosetests`? Any flags will go to `bin/python` instead.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the commands you have tried? You should change your question to clarify that `nosetests` is itself written in python using the `#!/usr/bin/python` and to give more details of what you are trying to do. You wish to use your custom `#!` python wrapper to pass args to python and you also wish to pass args to nosetest itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think that flags will go to `bin/python`? Have you tested this? If I write a simple program to test this out:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

I get the following ouput from these example calls (assuming I have saved this in a file called test.py)

`python test.py` prints `[]`

`python test.py 5` prints `['5']`

`python -i test.py 5` prints `['5']` (and then passes control to the interpreter because of the `-i` flag).

So flags **before** the script name are passed to Python, flags **after** the script name are passed to the script. So in your example, just use

```
bin/python /usr/local/bin/nosetests --with-snort
```

Some of this is convered in [Invoking the Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) in Python's documentation.

Comment: Yup... the problem was that `subprocess.check_output` was appending a '\n' to the end of the `which nosetests` check. This caused the flag to move to a new line and be treated as a new command. Same thing happens with ruby backticks. Just had to do an `rstrip`.